How to POST data from one Laravel app to another (different URLs)
I currently have an app locally on http://transmitting-app-local/, and it has a JavaScript file that POST data to another app on http://receiving-app-local/ using the fetch API.
I disabled the CSRF protection for the receiving app in the bootstrap/app.php:
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->validateCsrfTokens(except: [
            'http://transmitting-app-local/*'
        ]);
    })

But I still got Error 419 and the following CORS error in the browser:

Access to fetch at 'http://receiving-app-local/receive' from origin 'http://transmitting-app-local/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

Is this something I need to add to the POST request on the JavaScript side? Or also configure something on the receiving app CORS settings? If so, how can I do it?
I did publish the cors.php config file using php artisan config:publish cors on the receiving app, and I seem to have allowed CORS from everywhere and it still doesn't work:
// cors.php
    'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

And now there's no error in the browser but still the response is Error 419
Do I also need to configure the cors.php on the trasmitting app?

No, you only need to configure this on the app that you are making the request to. That second error message doesn't appear to make much sense, though. For one, the origin it says the request was made from, appears to match what it says the Access-Control-Allow-Origin contained, exactly. And secondly, not sure why it would respond with a specific origin, when in your config you used the wildcard *. (Maybe that's some automatism of Laravel though, dunno.)

Oh you are right, the second error message was after I tried to change the cors.php to the specific URL, my bad! (I changed to 'allowed_origins' => ['http://transmitting-app-local/'],)

@C3roe I updated the post, sorry for that

Can you try without the trailing slash? By definition, an Origin is <scheme>://<hostname> only, plus an optional port - but it should not include any path.

@C3roe I changed it back to 'allowed_origins' => ['*'] and the error in the browser disappeared but I still get response 419. Also I verified what you said and checked without the trailing slashes: 'allowed_origins' => ['http://transmitting-app-local'] and it really worked and didn't show the error on the browser as well, but still response 419

419 in Laravel means CSRF token missing or expired. "I disabled the CSRF protection for the receiving app" - it looks like you took except to mean what request origins would not require a token? That is not what it does. It specifies which requested routes do not require the token.

But if they do not require the token shouldn't it work when I simply remove the token from the fetch request? i.e. I removed formData.append("_token", this._token); from the JS script

"But if they do not require the token" - are you talking hypothetically here now? The endpoint you are targeting apparently does require a token, why else would you be getting the 419 response?

You have a point, so I need to see how to completely disable CSRF first and not just add exceptions

You don't need to disable it globally for everything, just for the routes you are trying to make requests to from the outside without a token. If your other app was only posting to http://receiving-app-local/foobar/, then you'd need to disable it for that route only. Or http://receiving-app-local/foobar/*, if you want to make requests to additional paths below this.

The except route you specify should be http://receiving-app-local/whatever-path-youre-posting-to/, or whatever-path-youre-posting-to/ (Difference between the two would only be relevant, if your Lavarel is serving content for multiple different host names. The latter would apply to /whatever-path-youre-posting-to/ under all the host names it serves, whereas the former would only for requests made to receiving-app-local)

So I completely got confused and the except should be on the app sending the POST request right? But, I now added the following to the except array in the verifyCsrfToken.php middleware on the sending app transmitting-app-local and still get 419: protected $except = ['http://receiving-app-local/*'];

@C3roe sorry I confused again and I think I got it now! I need to add ['http://receiving-app-local/*']; to the except array ON THE RECEIVING APP!!

@C3roe thank you! It's working now! The only thing that doesn't work is when I dd something on the receiving-app-local I don't see that in the devtools Preview tab, it only shows "Failed to load response data" so I guess dd in Laravel only works for the same app?

dd is "dump & die", your script will exit after that. The debug output will be added to the response - but that will most likely "invalidate" the response for the receiver in this scenario.
